# Creating a plugin's custom event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on a jQuery plugin called `popup`. This is my first jQuery plugin so I am trying to follow the tutorial on jQuery website. I want to implement something that I haven't found in their reference: an `onOkay( function(e){ });` event. I want the developer to be able to call this event handler like this:

```
$("#message").popup().onOkay(function( e ) {
    // some code here
});
```

What do I have to do to implement a code to work like this?

Comment: The standard way to offer callbacks is as options within your plugin call: $('#message').popup({onOkay: function(e) { ... }});

Comment: Before going any further, I suggest you look at http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/modal/

Comment: @Victor, before trying to roll up your own UI plugin paradigm, I would suggest you have a look at existing widget engines like the [jQuery UI widget factory](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/) ([more info](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory)). That factory is used by jQuery UI, jQuery Mobile and many other plugins, and the developers you are targeting  with your own plugin will be more efficient with it if it follows a pattern they already know (and for some, love).

Comment: Actually, the developers I am targeting, are the people working for developing my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just an event handler, have your plugin trigger said event, then you can bind to the event handler just like any other event.

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var $self = $(this);

        ... generate markup and show popup ...
        okbtn.on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if ( $self.triggerHandler("mypluginok") ) {
                // do your plugin stuff
            } 
        });

    });
};

$("#someel").myPlugin().on("mypluginok",function(){
    console.log("Ok button pressed!")
    // return false; // this would prevent the plugin's click handling
})
```

It is not suggested to add additional methods such as `onOkay` as that may conflict with other plugins if said other plugins also define an `onOkay` method on `$.fn`.

Comment: I get `Cannot call method "on" on undefined`

Comment: @Victor that means you missed this part: `return this.each(function(){` which is something that should (in my opinion) be part of every plugin assigned on `$.fn`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'll want to pass a function over into your plugin and use it as a callback. Here is some simple pseudo code to show an example:

```
plugin_func = function( params, callback ){
    // Do some awesome stuff with params
    var callback_arguments = 'foo' + params;
    callback( callback_arguments );
}
```

Now you call this function with a callback function like this :

```
plugin_func('bar', function( response ){ 
    console.log( response );
});
```

---

Here is even another method to use callbacks if you need to manipulate scope with your callbacks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

```
callback.apply( thisScope, [ array_of_args_passed_to_callback ]
```